# mysqlworkbench modify remote stored routines

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using mysqlworkbench to connect to a remote mysql database using a user 'userA'. I am able to select from tables, see the list of functions and stored procedures. I am not able to view/see the code of these functions and stored procedures. Is this because they are defined on the mysql server by user 'root@localhost'? How can I get the user 'usera' to edit view and edit these using mysqlqorkbench?

Comment: The user 'userA' need the edit/update rights on the specific view/function. currently it has the read-only rights.

Comment: how do I give these rights to the user?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have MySQL Workbench.

Just log in with the root user. Go to the Menu "Server->User and Privileges". There you'll see all the users in the left panel. Select 'userA' and then select 'Schema Privileges' from the tab right. Now select the schema on which you want to grant the rights. At the bottom you can see possible rights that can be assigned to the user. Select appropriate rights and Save.

I have MySQL Workbench 6.2.5.0. If you have a different version, please locate the User and Privileges accordingly. Hope that helps!